# Best way to filter points given a starting point and max travel time

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, network, service-area

I have a database of about 1M geolocated addresses and I'm looking for a way to sort/filter these records based on a starting point and max travel time.

Ex:

- "find every baker shop within 30 min of {where I am}"
- "find every {whatever} within 60 min of {my work address}"
- Optional: "find every {whatever} within 60 min of {where I am} AND 30 min of {my work address}"

Is there a known algorithm for this type of queries ?

It looks like PostGIS + pgRouting would fit the job, but I don't know where to start.

I'm looking for a server-side solution that I'll query with a PHP application.

Comment: sounds like you have already answered your own question in the question.

Comment: I'm new to the GIS world. I don't know if PostGIS is the best way to go, especially with 1M row + timetable data. What would be the expected performance ? Which PostGIS feature should I learn first ? Is there any other tool that address this problem specifically and would be better than PostGIS ?

Comment: expected performance would be based on what hardware (+RAM) and speed of your network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search term you need is "isochrone".  A web search should reveal techniques for creating your 30-minute (or 60-minute, or whatever) boundary.  With that, it's a simple intersection problem to find the contained points.